# Getting a coordinate through a spline with length defined

Tags: interpolation, splines

Through other software I managed to obtain a spline with length of 200mm.

[image]

The points would be these:

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {45, 10}, {75, -15}, {130, -20}, {180, -33.25904718}}
```

The last value in Y (`-33.25904718`) is not accurate for this directly depends on the length of the spline, that is 200.

1. I get this value in the SolidWorks software, but how can I get this value using Mathematica?

And another question:

2. There is only one solution or there may be several other?

**EDIT :**

Through the comments of [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) I think the answer is this documentation, but I couldn't find a way in which the length of the BSpline is an input.

[BSpline](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BSplineCurve.html?q=BSplineCurve)->Applications->Interpolation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming solving for the final y-coordinate is sought, which is what it sounds like:

```
len[y_?NumericQ] := 
 With[{spl = Interpolation[
    {{0, 0}, {45, 10}, {75, -15}, {130, -20}, {180, y}}, 
    Method -> "Spline"]},
  NIntegrate[Sqrt[1 + spl'[t]^2], {t, 0, 180}]]
```

Check OP's solution

```
len[-33.25904873]
(*  205.858  *)
```

Try to find a better one:

```
FindRoot[len[y] == 200, {y, 0}]
len[y] /. %
```

> FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function.... >>

```
(*
  {y -> -15.8953}
  202.674
*)
```

The answer to question 2 is that, yes, there could be more than one solution, but, in fact, there is not even one:

```
Plot[len[y], {y, -33, 0},
 GridLines -> {None, {200}},  PlotRange -> {200, 205}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Update --**

Here's the B-spline example from the docs (pointed out by the OP) adapted to the OP's problem.  It still shows it is impossible. Someone either will have to guess the correct basis, or perhaps the OP can find a suitable one.

```
ClearAll[len];
bs[y_?NumericQ] := Module[{pts, dist, param, knots, m, ctrlpts},
   pts = {{0, 0}, {45, 10}, {75, -15}, {130, -20}, {180, y}};
   dist = 
    Accumulate[
     Table[EuclideanDistance[pts[[i]], pts[[i + 1]]], {i, Length[pts] - 1}]];
   param = N[Prepend[dist/Last[dist], 0]];
   knots = {0, 0, 0, 0, 1/3, 2/3, 1, 1, 1, 1};
   m = Table[
     BSplineBasis[{3, knots}, j - 1, param[[i]]], {i, Length@param}, {j, 6}];
   ctrlpts = LinearSolve[m, pts];
   BSplineFunction[ctrlpts]
   ];
len[y_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Norm[D[bs[y][t], t]], {t, 0, 1}];
```

Solution:

```
splsol = FindRoot[len[y] == 200, {{y, 0}}]
len[y] /. splsol
(*
  {y -> -17.3114}
  201.19
*)
```

Comment: It is not necessary to obtain exactly one spline, could be a polynomial of fourth degree.

Comment: @LeandroMacieldeCarvalho With `InterpolationOrder -> 4`, the length is longer.  With `InterpolationOrder -> 2`, there are two solutions, `{y -> -39.7079}` and `{y -> -0.77588}`.

Comment: I made a new calculation in other software and got another value for y. Now I updated the question.

Comment: @LeandroMacieldeCarvalho What is their spline method?

Comment: Another thing I did was to change the `Method` for `Hermite` with the new value for `Y`. The result was closer.

Comment: @LeandroMacieldeCarvalho But `"Hermite"` won't produce a spline, per se, just an interpolation.

Comment: The software is based like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline

Comment: I'm sorry. I referred to the interpolation when I commented about `Hermite`